# Input image size in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation

Hi I am trying to get the image size of the uploaded image in MATLAB. So far I have got :

```
read=imread(image.png)

ymax=size(read) (1);
xmax=size(read) (2);
```

However this gives me an error. The image size is 300px by 256px, and I want my `ymax` and `xmax` to automatically get the pixel values. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a MATLAB'ish way of doing that, try:

```
[xmax, ymax, nchan] = size(read);
```

Where `nchan` is the number of channels. Also it can be done by:

```
xmax = size(read, 1);
ymax = size(read, 2);
```

Or even:

```
[xmax, ymax, ~] = size(read);
```